# PHPUnit: Where should I throw the exception (expectException method)?

Tags: php, phpunit

I know both versions are correct but I would like to know which is "better".
The problem with `expectException()` method is it is written before you type the method which launches the exception.

My question is, should I put them at the beginning of the method (to make them more visible) or otherwise only just before the method which causes the exception (I think it has more sense)?

- Option A)

```php
/** @test */
public function shouldThrowsAnException(): void
{
    $this->expectException(RuntimeException::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('Error message');

    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->bar(); // <-- This method launches the exception!!
}
```

- Option B)

```php
/** @test */
public function shouldThrowsAnException(): void
{
    $foo = new Foo();

    $this->expectException(RuntimeException::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('Error message');
    $foo->bar(); // <-- This method launches the exception!!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing unit tests, each unit should be testing only one thing.  So your `expectException` should be as specific as possible, as you have in your code, looking for a particular exception and a particular message.

If your constructor happened to throw the same exception, then Option B would be the better option, so you don't catch the constructor exception by accident. If the constructor does throw exceptions, you would then write other test cases that flush out the constructor.

If the constructor does not throw any exceptions, the two unit test are the same as far as execution.

If you were asking from a readability standpoint, then Option B is more readable, because it is clear that the expectation is that your method `Bar` will be throwing the exception.